# How can I get the brightness of outside environment by iPhone?

Tags: ios, brightness

As we know that iPhone's screen can adjust itself automatically as the brightness changes around, so it should get the brightness of the outside first, right? That's what I thought.
So now I just want to get the brightness of the outside environment throught its opt0-sensor, but I don't know how?

Can anybody be kind to help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the camera and get the degree of brightness with the help of some image processing techniques as far as i know. Otherwise the iPhone configurations detecting the outside ambiant light is quite blackboxed for devs.

Comment: yes, this is a way, but i just want to use the sensor but the camera, is there any ideas? and thanks btw.:)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309643/is-there-a-light-sensor-on-the-iphone-and-if-so-how-can-i-read-the-data), accessing the ambient light sensor data require access to private headers which is forbidden on the App Store.